# How can I set data to localStorage for subdomain?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a website example.com with main domain and separate one with classroom.example.com Now I'd like to set some data for classroom.example.com when user browse my main website with main domain example.com

How can I do that?

Comment: Yes I saw that but I couldn't make that possible for my problem. I got that like complicated one. Wait for the best answer

Comment: All possible answers were already given in dupe question.